# Unable to replicate Postgres tables using logical replication in RDS

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, pg-logical

Tables in the destination database are empty even after subscription is successful.
I am extremely new to logical replication within Postgres. I am trying to replicate three tables from the source database to the destination database.
These two databases are running on difference RDS instances

I followed the steps laid out on this link
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/AuroraPostgreSQL.Replication.Logical.html

I have enabled replication across both the database instances by changing the parameter `rds.logical_replication` to 1 (enabled). The parameter groups are in sync after the restart.

On the source database, I created a publication

`create publication master_data_publication for table tbl_1, tbl_2, tbl_3;`

On the destination I created a table with the same name and same columns and then created a subscription

`create subscription master_data_sub CONNECTION 'host=sourcedbhost.some-code.some-region.rds.amazonaws.com port=5432 dbname=sourcedb user=sourceuser password=userpassword' publication master_data_publication;`

if i run
`select * from pg_catalog.pg_stat_subscription;`, it shows the following. [image]
With this, we would assume that the replication should be working.

But the tables are shown to be completely empty.

On Source

```
select count(*) from tbl_1;
 count
-------
     332
```

On Destination

```
select count(*) from tbl_1;
 count
-------
     0
```

I am now stuck on how to proceed from here.

Comment: What versions are you using?

Comment: Have you looked in the log files?  "tbl_1" is not the same thing as "tbl1".  Is that a problem in your question, or in the real situation?

Comment: @jjanes I am using Postgres version 12.3. The tbl1/tbl_1 was a typo on my end. while posting this message.

Comment: What is in `select * from pg_catalog.pg_subscription` and `select * from pg_catalog.pg_subscription_rel`?

Comment: `select * from pg_catalog.pg_subscription_rel;`. 

srsubid | srrelid | srsubstate | srsublsn.  
---------+---------+------------+----------  
   61898 |   61853 | d          |. 
   61898 |   61886 | d          |.

Comment: `select * from pg_catalog.pg_subscription_rel;  `

```
  oid  | subdbid |     subname     | subowner | subenabled |   subslotname   | 
  subsynccommit |      subpublications
  -------+---------+-----------------+----------+------------+-----------------+---------------+----------- 
 ----------------
   61898 |   26885 | master_data_sub |    16399 | t          | master_data_sub | off           
  | {master_data_publication}
```
I removed the subconninfo column

Comment: srsubstate of 'd' means it is not yet ready.